# Where to mention port while giving hit to server?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, webserver, tomcat6

I have one small doubt and may be silly but I want to clear the doubt.

Say I have server computer in which I have tomcat and apache server running.

I can now access the admin page using 
"http://localhost:8080/" = Tomcat for java
"http://localhost/"      = Apache Server for php pages

So now when I access the url like 
http://www.abc.com/Construction/index.html
so it will go and hit which application ie apache or tomcat when both are having index.html page in it.

In short where we use to mention port?
http://www.abc.com/ in this url where is the application port mentioned also how do http protocol port 80 will come in picture in this?

Please clear my doubt.

Thanks

Comment: My question is how it will come to know which application to pass the control ie tomcat or apache for index.html page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When no port is specified the `http://` protocol defaults to port 80. `http://localhost/` is equivalent to `http://localhost:80/`.

`http://www.abc.com/Construction/index.html` will connect to the host `www.abc.com` on port 80, then request the URL `/Construction/index.html`. Since you have Tomcat running on port 8080 and Apache on port 80, Apache would be the one to handle this request.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the protocol being used. If a port number is not specified, then the default port for that protocol will be used. For HTTP its 80, while for HTTPS its 443.

And only one web server can serve/bind on a port. So if you have IIS and Tomcat running in same machine. Both will have to run on different ports.
So for http://www.abc.com/ will be served by the web server running on port 80.